# Flume doesn't call the stop method of the last Agent

Tags: flume

I'm working with Flume. I have a external program which modifies the flume.conf. 
When I modify the configuration file, Flume reloads the new configuration, changing, creating or removing the agents depending the new flume.conf.

Basically, when you modify the file, FLume calls all the stop methods of your agents and after that the starts methods of your agents what are present in your flume.conf. But, if you remove all the agents that there're in my flume.conf (or you only had once) it doesn't work. Flume detects that there're changes in your file, but there're nothing right now in the file, it's empty and Flume doesn't call the stop methods, so if I had some agents, the agents will never stop. 
I'm talking about the Agents, not about Flume. Flume doesn't have to stop, because you could want to add new agents in the future.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or it's the normal performance.